# Missing Install Font Command in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I've followed along with this link:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/install-or-uninstall-fonts

However, when I hit ALT to bring up FILE, there is no Add Font prompt.  See the image below.

[image]

Also note the link above says Vista but my Google search said this is supposed to be a tutorial for Windows 7, which is what I want.  Can someone help me explain about installing my new font on Win 7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial to fix this, so I wanted to post it here for others who may have the same question.  Here's the tutorial I used:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1155-fonts-install.html